# Why does this happen when I grep over an undefined array?

Tags: perl, grep

Does anybody know why this happens?

```
$ perl -e '@arr = []; print "HELLO." unless grep {/asdf/ =~ $_} @arr;'
```

Outputs:

```
HELLO.
```

But

```
$ perl -e '@arr = undef; print "HELLO." unless grep {/asdf/ =~ $_} @arr;'
```

Outputs nothing.

To me, it seems like both should output "HELLO."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors in your code, which are causing the unexpected results.

First, if you want an empty array, you need to write:

```
# Correct (creates an empty array)
my @array = ();

# Incorrect (creates a one-element array containing a reference to an empty array)
my @array = [];

# Incorrect (creates a one-element array containing the undef element)
my @array = undef;
```

You also need to reverse the grep condition -- the regular expression should be on the right side of the `=~` operator:

```
perl -e '@arr = (); print "HELLO." unless grep { $_ =~ /asdf/} @arr;'
```

If you make those two changes, the code will do what you expect.

Comment: "my @array;" creates an empty array. Some have the opinion that "my @array = ();" is more clear or something, but the former is sufficient and more perlish.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want grep { $_ =~ /asdf/ }.  The value on the left side of =~ is the value to match against, and the right side is the regular expression.  This could be simplified further as grep { /asdf/ } because $_ is searched by default.

As written, you're trying to match an undef pattern against a regex value.  The match operator (I believe) always returns true when the pattern is undef.